# PySpark - Error "IndexOutOfBoundsException: No group 2" after using df.select(*column_list)

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have searched and searched but I cannot find an answer to this.

I have a function that essentially sorts columns (according to their name and datatype) into a specific order that my company requires before saving DataFrames to SQL. I know this function works. All it does is output a list of columns (found in the source DataFrame). I call this list of sorted column names **col_list**, and I utilize this list by using it as an argument for df.select().

This method has worked fine for months. However, on one particular project, when I try to apply the sort to the dataframe via:

```
df = df.select(*col_list)
```

...I get this error:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 1 in stage 63.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 1.3 in stage 63.0 (TID 583) (10.139.64.7 executor 4): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: No group 2
    at java.util.regex.Matcher.start(Matcher.java:375)
    at java.util.regex.Matcher.appendReplacement(Matcher.java:880)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage12.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:759)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:168)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.ShuffleWriteProcessor.write(ShuffleWriteProcessor.scala:59)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.$anonfun$runTask$3(ShuffleMapTask.scala:81)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.$anonfun$runTask$1(ShuffleMapTask.scala:81)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:53)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:41)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.doRunTask(Task.scala:153)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.$anonfun$run$1(Task.scala:122)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:93)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$13(Executor.scala:824)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1667)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$4(Executor.scala:827)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:683)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:2979)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2(DAGScheduler.scala:2926)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:2920)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:2920)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1(DAGScheduler.scala:1340)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:1340)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:407)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:1340)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:3188)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:3129)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:3117)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: No group 2
    at java.util.regex.Matcher.start(Matcher.java:375)
    at java.util.regex.Matcher.appendReplacement(Matcher.java:880)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage12.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:759)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:168)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.ShuffleWriteProcessor.write(ShuffleWriteProcessor.scala:59)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.$anonfun$runTask$3(ShuffleMapTask.scala:81)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.$anonfun$runTask$1(ShuffleMapTask.scala:81)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:53)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:41)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.doRunTask(Task.scala:153)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.$anonfun$run$1(Task.scala:122)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:93)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$13(Executor.scala:824)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1667)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$4(Executor.scala:827)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:683)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
---
```

Troubleshooting so far:

1. Is col_list a true list? Is it nested or flat?

- **Yes, it is a true list, and it is not nested.**

2. Do all items in col_list have type string?

- **Yup, checked that too. All strings.**

3. Does any item in col_list correspond to a column not actually present in df.schema.fieldNames()?

- **Also checked this. Every single item in col_list corresponds to a present column name in df.**

4. Does the error change in anyway if you use df = df.select(col_list) instead of df = df.select(*col_list) (remove the asterisk '*')?

- **Checked that too. Asterisk or no asterisk, I get the same error.**

Any assistance anyone can provided would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem. I was paying attention to the wrong thing. It had to do with one of my .withColumn() statements...

```
chasefact = chasefact.withColumn('Product', F.when(F.col('InterchangeQualificationDescription').rlike('Product [0-9]'),
                                                       F.regexp_replace(F.col('InterchangeQualificationDescription'),
                                                                        '(.*)(Product )([0-9])(.*)',
                                                                        '$2$3')))\
                     .join(DimCardProduct, how='left', on='Product').drop('Product')
```

The problem seemed to be that the string pattern I was searching for in .rlike() and the string pattern I was searching for in F.regexp_replace() were not the same. I guess that means that it is going to try to apply a substitution on a group that isn't necessarily in the given string value.

Lesson Learned: When using .rlike() and F.regexp_replace() together, make sure the regexp search pattern/substring is exactly the same between them!